# SSH Connection working on Terminal to Ubuntu-server but not showing on website on same machine

Tags: server, ssh, 22.04, apache2, openssh

Looking at other questions I have gone through and tried various methods but the problem I am having is when I log into the ubuntu-server via terminal it works correctly, I am able to do all the commands. The trouble I am having is it is not allowing me to log in via a browser. I am trying to implement a Apache2, I have clear browser data and other parts, there are no proxies set. I am not using a virtual machine, it is an old mac mini converted to ubuntu-server 22.04

I am running trend micro on my Mac which I am using to access the terminal. This started last night and it has continued this morning. I have rebooted the Modem, checked proxies and even shut down my anti-virus to test, to no avail.

I have also set a static ip address for the server, and checked to make sure there is no doubling of the address, the server is outside the range allowed in my settings. 100 - 200, serer is set on 222

error displayed on browser

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Am I missing something?

Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-76-generic x86_64)

System information as of Thu 13 Jul 23:53:13 UTC 2023

System load: 0.1884765625

Usage of /: 7.0% of 97.87GB

Memory usage: 3%

Swap usage: 0%

Temperature: 54.0 C

Processes: 154

Users logged in: 0

IPv4 address for enp4s0: -----------------

IPv6 address for enp4s0: ------------------

Thank you any help would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with a proxy in the end. I wrote it in at port 8080 when I removed it to show just 80, it worked.  Seems I must have set it on the server without realising I did?

Thank you